# First Heroku deploy failed `error code=H10`

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I deployed my app to Heroku. It's a node.js + express + socket.io app and this is the `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "game_test",
  "author": "Ilya",
  "description": "A test app for our board game",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.0.6",
    "jade": "*",
    "socket.io" : "*"
  },
 "engines": {
      "node": "0.8.14"
  }
}
```

This is the log I get:

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=game-test-1.herokuapp.com fwd=37.26.146.185 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=game-test-1.herokuapp.com fwd=37.26.146.185 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

What does it mean?

Comment: "App crashed" has the obvious meaning: your app crashed. Look further up in your logs to see why, or `heroku restart` to launch it again so you can watch it crash again.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Found solution for me here: [Heroku + node.js error (Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of)

In my case, my app crashed because it was hard setting the PORT, instead of using the port that heroku dynamically sets, which can be accessed with `process.env.PORT`

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

Comment: These days most of us are using ES6. So same answer can also be written in ES6 using arrow function. app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});

Comment: This happened to me, which was caused by trying to import a library that was not in my package.json file.

Comment: Where should the above mentioned line of code be added?

Comment: @PraveenKumar-M usually that line goes in the main file of your server (index.js). `app` is an instance of express

Comment: I get `TypeError: this.address is not a function` in `Node V17`.

Comment: The improved `string-ish` way is `app.listen(process.env.port || 3000, () => {// port = this.address().port; console.log(`listening in ${app.settings.env} mode`);});`

Answer (score 67):

I just had a similar issue with my app, I got the issue after a migration of the DB, after trying many options, the one that helped me was this:

```
heroku restart
```

(Using Heroku toolbelt for mac)

Comment: I was getting the same error code and mine used to work but this all of a sudden started happening.  The "heroku restart" command cleared this up for me.

Comment: Same thing happened to me after adding New Relic. Restart fixed my issue

Comment: My app was working on localhost and if that's the case `heroku restart` is the correct thing to do first. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

I had this issue, the only problem was my Procfile was like this

```
web : node index.js
```

and I changed to

```
web:node index.js
```

the only problem was spaces

Comment: Pretty sure the colon needs to be placed like `web: node index.js` and removing that space I show is optional

Comment: Procfile no longer required for Node.js apps. Article Link : https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/370

Comment: Worked for me I changed this web:node index.js and then add it and commit it and then runs git push heroku master

Answer (score 7):

In my case, i found same error because there  is version difference of node and npm on my local machine and defined in package.json version.

```
"engines": {
  "node": "0.8",
  "npm": "1.2.x"
}
```

when i check using

```
node --version : v0.10.41
npm --version : 1.4.29
```

when i update my package.json to

```
 "engines": {
  "node": "0.10.41",
  "npm": "1.4.29"
}
```

It works fine :)

Answer (score 7):

In my case there was no start command in the script section of `package.json` file.
When I created the `package.json` file with `npm init` I did not create a start script command.
So I went to the `package.json` file, under scripts I added a new entry:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
```

Saved it and uploaded to Heroku and it worked

Comment: How should I know what should I write inside start? any file that end with js?

Answer (score 6):

in my case adding `process.env.PORT || 3000` to my http server script, resolved.
My heroku log reported 'H20' error and 503 http status.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, my Procfile was pointing to the wrong file (bot.js which I previously used) so once I updated it, the error was gone.

Answer (score 3):

Also check your database connection. I forgot to change my database connection from localhost and this crashed my app once it was pushed to heroku.

Comment: What do you mean? I have my mongodb connection on localhost. What should I change it to?

Answer (score 3):

I faced this same problem and none of the answers above helped me.
What i did was run:

```
node --version
```

and in the package.json add the engines section with your node version:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "description": "a really cool app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

upon using hapi18, I find taking out the "host" field and setting the port to:

`port: process.env.PORT || 5000` did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Old Thread, but I fix this issue by setting PORT constant to process.env.PORT ||

For some weird reason, it wanted to search Env first.

Answer (score 2):

I had a typo

`const PORT = process.env.PORT||'8080';`

used to be

`const PORT = process.env.port||'8080';`

Answer (score 2):

If you locally start node server by `nodemon`, like I did, and it locally works, try `npm start`. Nodemon was telling me no errors, but npm start told me a lot of them in a understandable way and then I could solve them by following another posts here. I hope it helps to someone.

Answer (score 1):

In my own case, i got this error because i refuse to add a Procfile to my node js app and my  "main": "app.js" was initially pointing to another js file as main. so doing these chnages get it fixed for me

Answer (score 1):

Password contained a % broke it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I forgot to set database env for deployment.
you can set env by this command
(I'm using mLab for MongoDB server)

heroku config:set MONGO_URI='mongodb://address'

Answer (score 1):

For me it was Package.json it was empty from dependencies even though i thought i did install them.. so I had to reinstall them with --save option in the end and verify they were added to the package.json.. and then push it again and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

My port was set to `config.httpPort` which resolves to `80`. I fixed it by doing this:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || config.httpPort;

app.listen(PORT, ...)
```

Thanks a lot, it wasted me a lot of hours last night.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had **code=H10** and **status=503** because my 
Procfile:

```
web: node build/server.js
```

and I included **/build** in **.gitignore**

Answer (score 1):

My `start` command had `env-cmd -f ./config/prod.env node index.js`.

after changing to: `node index.js` it got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, the problem was my Profile was like this:

`web: gunicorn__init__:app`

Notice with the above there was no space between **gunicorn** and **__ init __**

instead of
`web: gunicorn __init__:app`

Answer (score 1):

in my case the problem solved by changing the order :
From :
app.listen(2000 || process.env.PORT);
to :
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 2000);

Answer (score 1):

Just got this error and resolved it. For anyone who has tried the other methods and failed, do check your Procfile path. My server was in the backend folder yet I only typed web: node server.js. I resolved the error after changing it to web: node backend/server.js

Answer (score 0):

I got the same above error as "app crashed" and H10 error and the heroku app logs is not showing much info related to the error msg reasons. Then I restarted the dynos in heroku and then it showed the error saying additional curly brace in one of the index.js files in my setup. The issue got fixed once it is removed and redeployed the app on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

The H10 error code could mean many different things. In my case, the first time was because I didn't know that Heroku isn't compatible with Sqlite3, the second time was because I accidentally pushed an update with Google analytics working in development as well as production.

Answer (score 0):

Older thread, but for me I didn't set my `.env` vars in the Heroku console.

Answer (score 0):

i was using body-Parser that throw exception

```
const bodyParser = require('body-Parser')    
//Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(bodyparser.json())
```

intead of using

```
    //Bodyparser Middleware
    app.use(express.json())
```

this resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I want to register here what was my solution for this error which was a simple file not updated to Github.

I have a full stack project, and my files are structured both root directory for backend and client for the frontend (I am using React.js). All came down to the fact that I was mistakenly pushing the client folder only to Github and all my changes which had an error (missing a comma in a object's instance in my index.js) was not updated in the backend side. Since this Heroku fetches all updates from Github Repository, I couldn't access my server and the error persisted. Then all I had to do was to commit and push to the root directory and update all the changes of the project and everything came back to work again.

Answer (score 0):

I struggle with the same error for hours, but I was able to solve it. I installed multer and aws-sdk as a devDependencies by mistake, instead of just dependencies. 
So, anyone who has the same error, just double-check your package.json file.

Also, a small tip for the property of the engine in package.json.

```
enter code here
//The greater or equal operators will make sure that you use the right node 
//version 
//even if your current node is greater version than npm node

"engines": {
"node": ">= 0.8.14"
},


//insted of
"engines": {
  "node": "0.8.14"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was deploying python Django framework when I got this error because I forget to put my app name `web: gunicorn plaindjango.wsgi:application --log-file -` instead of `plaindjango`

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had things unnecessarily split into separate folders. I'm running plotly dash and I had my `Procfile`, and `Pipfile` (and lock) together, but separate from the other features of my app (`run.py` and `app.py`, the actual content of the pages being used was in a subfolder). So joining much of that together repaired my H10 error

Answer (score 0):

```
// PORT
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8081;

// Listen on port 8081
app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Application is listening on port ${PORT}!`)
);
```

process.env.PORT will handle whatever port is needed on, for example, Heroku, AWS etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to the heap memory limit.

1. Just add some of the dependencies to the dev dependencies object.
2. Remove unused modules.

You can see the exact error using `heroku restart` and if it is the memory limit, then upgrade your heroku account.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem (H10 GET=/). I tried changing PORT but with no results.
Turns out the solution was simple. I edited one line in my package.json file.
From:

```
 "scripts": {
 "start": "nodemon app.js"
```

To:

```
 "scripts": {
 "start": "node app.js"
```