# Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am deploying a node.js app on heroku. The code looks like this:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var ip_addr = "127.0.0.1";
server.listen(port, ip_addr, function() {
    console.log("%s listening at %s ", server.name, server.url);
});
```

I don't know why I get Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch node.js
error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The resolution specified under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of worked for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would imagine it has something to do with being explicit about the IP address.  Try just doing server.listen(port, function() { ... ?

Comment: Thanks! You're right. I think heroku tries to listen at url 0.0.0.0

Comment: if anyone has the same problem, for me what sabed was http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000) (i'm usig express)

Answer (score 0):

I thought that you're deploying to Heroku. Heroku is assigning a random port to the environment of the application. You can take this random port to your code like this way.

```
process.env.PORT
```

My sample code an I've used to do is here:

```
// production
config.port = process.env.PORT

app.listen(config.port, () => {
  logger.info('Listening on port %d', config.port);
});
```