# Fix error "at=error code=H10 desc "app crashed" method = GET

Tags: heroku, express, deployment, port

I am getting an error in my heroku logs that I cannot figure out how to fix.

I read through a thread on stack overflow [Heroku + node.js error (Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of).  This seemed very similar to my problem.

I have developing my app with the express generator.  So my bin folder holds the port information

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
```

I know the process.env.PORT is necessary to open my heroku site.  I initially assumed this would work well enough as my app.js only had a reference to express.

I could not get the page to open so I added the port information to my app.js file in addition to the bin folder.

```
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

I got this github page    https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/blob/master/index.js#L16.

However, I am still getting the same error.  I do not know where else to look.   The only additional note I see with an error is

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within  60 seconds of launch.
```

These seem to be targeting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What else is your app doing?

Note that the error indicates you didn't bind to the socket within 60 seconds.  I agree that your `app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));` looks just fine.

Maybe it's something else - maybe you're making a web callout or something before it even gets to that point, and that's what's consuming the time?