# Heroku R10 (Boot Timeout) error with Node app - but not using an HTTP server?

Tags: node.js, heroku, twitter

I have a simple Node.js app hosted on Heroku that consumes a Twitter stream. It works fine sometimes, but when I review my logs, I see it has begun to crash regularly with an [R10 error code](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r10-boot-timeout).

I've done a good deal of googling for other questions on this topic, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of), and the consensus seems to be that Heroku requires you to listen to process.env.PORT instead of explicitly setting your own port. Fair enough.

**But I'm not setting a port anywhere in my code,** and nor do I set up an http.createServer where I can .listen to one. So how can I solve this error? Any ideas?

Here's my code for reference:

```
var config = require('./config');
var count = require('./count');
var Twit = require('twit'); 
var T = new Twit(config);

port = process.env.PORT;  // this is just for reference, not used anywhere

var stream = T.stream('user', {track: "@isitoveryet2016"});

stream.on('connect', function (request) {
    console.log("Opening Twitter stream...");
}); 

stream.on('connected', function (response) {
    console.log("Connected and streaming on port: " + port);
});

stream.on('tweet', function (tweet){
    if (tweet.text.charAt(0) == "@"){
        if (tweet.user.screen_name == "isitoveryet2016") {
        console.log("Ignoring my own reply.");
        } else {
        var thisTweet = count.TimeLeft();
        console.log("Received direct tweet from: " + tweet.user.screen_name);
        console.log("Text: " + tweet.text);
        T.post('statuses/update', {in_reply_to_status_id: tweet.id_str, status: "@" + 
        tweet.user.screen_name + 
        thisTweet}, function (err, data, res){
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            else console.log('tweet deployed!');
            });
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("Not a direct tweet, not replying.");
    }
});

stream.on('warning', function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});

stream.on('disconnect', function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});

function handleError(err) {
  console.error('response status:', err.statusCode);
  console.error('data:', err.data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you have a `web` process that's expected to listen on port 80. You can change that to a non-web process by creating a Procfile, like:

```
worker: node twitter.js
```

Then telling Heroku to use just your worker, and to not expect a web process:

```
heroku scale web=0 worker=1
```

(at least, I'm fairly certain that should do what you want. It's very rare for apps not to have a web server involved somewhere)

(also: you don't need to do the `process.env.PORT` thing if you don't plan on using it. We don't look at your code, we just expect any `web` process to eventually bind to `$PORT`)

*disclosure: I'm the Node.js Platform Owner at Heroku.*

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, and it works, but now it seems to be duplicating my app. In the logs, I'm now getting 2x the console responses:

app[worker.1] "Console response"  
app[run.123] "Console response"  
app[run.456] "Console response"  

I'm a little confused. Am I duplicating my own processes here?

Comment: If you only see app[worker.1] (and nothing like app[worker.2] or app[web.1]) then you've only got a single instance of your app running.

Comment: Okay... so I now seem to be running both a [worker.1] instance AND a app[run.1234] instance of my application. I can manually run `heroku stop` to stop the app instance, but is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: `app[run.1234]` is created when you run a one-off command like `heroku run bash`.