# Keep getting an application error when trying to deploy a node app in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have been having difficulties deploying on heroku. Followed the deploying a node js app on heroku guide but still keep getting an application error. any idea why please? here is my heroku logs

```
 heroku logs
2015-10-27T19:48:35.704758+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by chineduabalogu@gmail.com
2015-10-27T19:48:35.704758+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by chineduabalogu@gmail.com
2015-10-27T19:57:58.536860+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-10-27T19:57:58.536871+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-10-27T19:57:58.397214+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by chineduabalogu@gmail.com
2015-10-27T19:57:58.466140+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 51bdb1d by chineduabalogu@gmail.com
2015-10-27T19:57:58.466140+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by chineduabalogu@gmail.com
2015-10-27T19:58:00.692453+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2015-10-27T19:58:03.827532+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-10-27T19:58:03.827554+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2015-10-27T19:58:03.827552+00:00 app[web.1]: > gf17@0.0.1 start /app
2015-10-27T19:58:03.827555+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-10-27T19:58:04.616168+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 3000
2015-10-27T19:59:00.972722+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-10-27T19:59:00.972722+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-10-27T19:59:01.940288+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-10-27T19:59:01.941567+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-10-27T19:59:01.932037+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-10-27T19:59:04.247002+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2015-10-27T19:59:07.923766+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-10-27T19:59:07.923776+00:00 app[web.1]: > gf17@0.0.1 start /app
2015-10-27T19:59:07.923778+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2015-10-27T19:59:07.923779+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-10-27T19:59:09.513389+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 3000
2015-10-27T20:00:04.705994+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-10-27T20:00:04.705994+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-10-27T20:00:05.657468+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-10-27T20:00:05.644215+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-10-27T20:17:45.559370+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=evening-fjord-8286.herokuapp.com request_id=ce9f7865-5431-4514-83e3-9228df351291 fwd="154.118.30.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-10-27T20:17:46.110795+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=evening-fjord-8286.herokuapp.com request_id=e7b1f9b7-4600-4ce7-b90c-3239a82abcb9 fwd="154.118.30.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-10-27T20:17:48.086903+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=evening-fjord-8286.herokuapp.com request_id=8a41518c-cfd8-4dac-8622-1f94de9346b3 fwd="198.15.118.148" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-10-27T20:17:48.543167+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=evening-fjord-8286.herokuapp.com request_id=e1ce271b-7a76-43c1-931e-0ac9a375cfb7 fwd="154.118.30.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-10-27T20:19:48.784831+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=evening-fjord-8286.herokuapp.com request_id=9229308a-6604-4426-8ba6-4cabb8b94de9 fwd="154.118.30.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-10-27T20:19:49.552910+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=evening-fjord-8286.herokuapp.com request_id=e542cc92-ca00-4044-8c23-76642887ef35 fwd="154.118.30.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-10-27T20:22:17.304691+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-10-27T20:22:19.261727+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2015-10-27T20:22:21.447920+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-10-27T20:22:21.447934+00:00 app[web.1]: > gf17@0.0.1 start /app
2015-10-27T20:22:21.447935+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2015-10-27T20:22:21.447936+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-10-27T20:22:22.123539+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 3000
2015-10-27T20:23:19.916089+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-10-27T20:23:19.916089+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-10-27T20:23:20.780482+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-10-27T20:23:20.792567+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-10-27T20:25:54.984210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=evening-fjord-8286.herokuapp.com request_id=83eec29d-598c-44d1-b6bc-55933e60013f fwd="154.118.30.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-10-27T20:25:56.659875+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=evening-fjord-8286.herokuapp.com request_id=c384f7e6-e6e9-4088-bdf1-b7370b572b68 fwd="154.118.30.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku + node.js error (Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of)

Answer (score 1):

From your logs, it looks like you are NOT binding to the right port.

I'm going to assume that your Express.js app looks something like this:

```
app.listen(3000);
```

This line of code tells Express.js to start running a web server on port 3000. This is fine when you're writing code on your laptop, but when you deploy code to Heroku, Heroku will assign you a RANDOM port number that you MUST bind to.

So, to fix your problem, you should rewrite the above line of code to look like this:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

This will tell your app to run on the correct Heroku port, but fall back to port 3000 when doing development on your local laptop =) This is the best of both worlds.

Hope this helps!