# Hapi server on heroku fails to bind port

Tags: heroku, reactjs, port, babeljs, hapi.js

I'm working on a Hapi server for a ReactJS app but when I try to deploy to Heroku, I get the R10 error "Failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch". What is going on? I'm using process.env.PORT. I also tried parseInt() around it. Also tried disabling varying packages. The build is successful always.

In the Heroku logs, I see the console log from the index.js ("Hapi running on ...") but then the R10 error shows up and the server restarts, then crashes.

==>  Hapi Production Server (API) is listening on http://localhost:14316
  2016-01-22T15:10:33.947571+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
  2016-01-22T15:10:33.947571+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web   process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
  2016-01-22T15:10:34.737554+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to    crashed
  2016-01-22T15:10:34.724233+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137

This all runs fine locally when I run with NODE_ENV=production

src/server.js

```
import Hapi from 'hapi';
import Inert from 'inert';
import jwt from 'hapi-auth-jwt2';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { RoutingContext, match } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import createRoutes from './routes';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import Html from './Html';

const PROTOCOL = 'http://';
const SERVER_HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const SERVER_PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const API_HOST = process.env.API_HOST || 'localhost';
const API_PORT = process.env.API_PORT || 8000;

export default function(callback) {

    const server = new Hapi.Server();

    server.connection({
    host: SERVER_HOST,
    port: SERVER_PORT,
    labels: ['api'],
    // routes: {
    //   cors: {
    //     origin: [PROTOCOL + API_HOST + ':' + API_PORT]
    //   }
    // }
  });

    server.connections[0].name = 'API';

    server.register([
        { register: Inert },
        { register: jwt },
        // {
      //   register: api,
      //   routes: {
      //     prefix: '/api'
      //   }
      // }
    ], (err) => {
    if(err) {
      console.error('ERROR:', err)
      throw err;
    }

        server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{param*}',
        handler: {
          directory: {
            path: 'static'
          }
        }
      });

        server.ext('onPreResponse', (request, reply) => {

            if (typeof request.response.statusCode !== 'undefined') {
        return reply.continue();
      }

            const assets = {
                javascript: {
                    main: '/dist/bundle.js'
                }
            };

          const store = configureStore();
          const routes = createRoutes(store);

          // this gets called if server side rendering/routing has problems and errors
          function hydrateOnClient() {
            reply('<!doctype html>\n' +
              renderToString(<Html assets={assets} store={store} />)).code(500);
          }

          match({ routes, location: request.path }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {

            if (redirectLocation) {

              res.redirect(301, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)

            } else if (error) {
              console.error('ROUTER ERROR:', error) // eslint-disable-line no-console
              hydrateOnClient();

            } else if (!renderProps) {

              // in some cases this would act as a 404 but that should be handled in the routes
              hydrateOnClient();

            } else {

              const component = (
                <Provider store={store}>
                  <RoutingContext {...renderProps} />
                </Provider>
              );

              reply('<!doctype html>\n' +
                renderToString(<Html assets={assets} component={component} store={store} />)
                    );
            }
          });
        });
    });

    return server.start((err) => {

        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        }

        callback(server)
    });

}
```

index.js

```
require('babel-core/register');

global.__DEVELOPMENT__ = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
global.__SERVER__ = true;
global.__CLIENT__ = false;

const server = require('./src/server');

server(server => {
   for (var key of Object.keys(server.connections)) {
     console.info('==>  Hapi Production Server (' + server.connections[key].name + ') is listening on', server.connections[key].info.uri);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`process.env.HOST` was undefined on Heroku, and for some reason it didn't like `localhost` as the host, which caused the issue.

I simply removed the host var all together, so connection looks like:

```
server.connection({
  port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
  labels: ['api'],
})
```

Comment: thank you! this was starting to drive me nuts because I had the process.env.PORT set up just fine. it was indeed that Heroku didn't like 

`server.connection({ port: PORT, host: 'localhost' });`

removing the `host` param entirely, as you suggested, worked. as such:
`server.connection({ port: PORT });`

cheers!

Comment: I had the same problem and I also resolved it by not defining the `host` property

Comment: ~2 hrs wasted today trying to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious to know how did you find this? It was even breaking my MySQL connection.