# Deploying nodeJS to Heroku internal error

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-deployment, web-hosting, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to upload NodeJS app to Heroku. Everything installs fine and when I run

```
heroku local
```

Then everything works as expected on a local host. But when I run

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
heroku open
```

Browser opens, and it is loading the page for like 2-3 minutes, or even more and then I receive Application error. I am new to web development so that any ideas will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the error logs to the question? You can check the logs by running the command `heroku logs`.

Comment: @gnerkus solved that, thank you so much, I didn't know about logs. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [gnerkus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2259144/gnerkus) I managed to figure that out.
In logs I found next error:

```
heroku Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT
```

Heroku dynamically assigns port to app and I was doing it manually:

```
app.listen(4000, function () {
```

Instead i just need listen like this:

```
.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)
```

Answer was here: 
[Heroku + node.js error (Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of)