# Heroku web process not binding to $PORT

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

With the first line below you can see where I had echoed `$PORT`, then below you can see `superstatic` listening on that port. However I got the below error. Any thoughts?

```
2017-07-02T23:45:02.675352+00:00 app[web.1]: 48775
2017-07-02T23:45:05.011757+00:00 app[web.1]:   Superstatic started.
2017-07-02T23:45:05.011772+00:00 app[web.1]: Visit http://localhost:48775 to view your app.
2017-07-02T23:46:01.224244+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-07-02T23:46:01.134116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

Comment: Can you share the code you use to bind the port in your app?

Comment: are you making a port assignment per the heroku node convention using "listen"  ?  see accepted ans : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of