# Heroku local invalid port number or address:port pair - deploying django app

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have this `ProcFile` file following this [guidelines for django app deployment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python) on section [Build your app and run it locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#build-your-app-and-run-it-locally) in order to test it locally you have to run this command.

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Then running `heroku local` or `heroku local web` got me into this error:

```
CommandError: "0.0.0.0:$PORT" is not a valid port number or address:port pair.
```

Comment: Sorry if my question is silly but did you try to input number instead of $PORT, like this: `web: python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000`:)

Comment: im trying now and it seems to work however i had to wait for the process which taking so long.. :)

Comment: its working now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must **not** use runserver in production. Use gunicorn as the docs and comments suggest.

Comment: Im following the guidelines in the link provided in my question, im taking the step to run the app locally using `heroku local web` command. I will not know how to deploy this app without following it first.

Comment: **Nothing** in that linked document mentions using runserver. It uses gunicorn throughout, and so should you.

Comment: Please look at this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#build-your-app-and-run-it-locally it is under the Build your app and run it locally section, a suggestion for windows user

Answer (score 1):

**For local:**

If you follow this official heroku [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#define-a-procfile) and you are running it on **Window platform locally**, instead of `$PORT`, you have to use `%PORT%` at your `Procfile.windows`:

`web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:%PORT%`

since window does not interpret `$PORT` expression which only applicable in Unix shells.

If one using `waitress` as WSGI and wanna run it **locally on Window platform**, your `Procfile` should looks like this:

`web: waitress-serve --port=%PORT% wsgi:your_app`

**For real online deployment:**

simply include `gunicorn` package in `requirementx.txt` and your `Procfile` should be in this way:

`web: gunicorn wsgi:your_app`

If you are using `waitress`, you need to change back to `$PORT`, and set it in this way instead of fixed port number since [Heroku assigns port to your app dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15693371/9960491). Also, do make sure the host is set to `0.0.0.0` so your app is available externally.

Answer (score 0):

For a django project in heroku you must have a Procfile like this:

```
web: gunicorn yourapp.wsgi
```

The filename must be `Procfile`, and not `ProcFile`

If you want to run into development you can either `$ python manage.py runserver` in your shell (heroku independent) or run `$ heroku local` with a valid production Procfile

Comment: I mean a Procfile exactly like this. As @DanielRoseman said, you must not use runserver. And be carefull with the file name uppercase.

Comment: Oh yes, but im following the guideline to test my app locally using heroku local web commandline, it is the step necessary to learn deployment.

Comment: If you want to run into development you can either `$ python manage.py runserver` in your shell (heroku independent) or run `$ heroku local` with a valid production Procfile.