# Webpack issues with Heroku and simple React App

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack

I usually use create-react-app to make apps... but I'm trying to do it with webpack. I am following this tutorial: https://www.adrianprieto.com/building-a-react-js-app-from-scratch-in-10-steps/

Having some issues with Heroku. The app is EXTREMELY simple. Literally two components with only text. It works fine locally. But when I try to launch on Heroku, it stalls. Here are the Heroku logs:

```
2018-02-14T14:43:34.679287+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user jackseabolt@gmail.com
2018-02-14T14:43:34.577090+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user jackseabolt@gmail.com
2018-02-14T14:43:34.679287+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user jackseabolt@gmail.com
2018-02-14T14:43:34.577090+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user jackseabolt@gmail.com
2018-02-14T14:47:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user jackseabolt@gmail.com
2018-02-14T14:47:52.513572+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 69edb643 by user jackseabolt@gmail.com
2018-02-14T14:47:52.531533+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user jackseabolt@gmail.com
2018-02-14T14:47:52.513572+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user jackseabolt@gmail.com
2018-02-14T14:47:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-02-14T14:47:56.429389+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-02-14T14:47:58.193319+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-02-14T14:47:58.193341+00:00 app[web.1]: > star-quizes-client@1.0.0 start /app
2018-02-14T14:47:58.193343+00:00 app[web.1]: > webpack-dev-server --hot
2018-02-14T14:47:58.193345+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-02-14T14:47:59.336099+00:00 app[web.1]: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
2018-02-14T14:47:59.336586+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack output is served from /
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683126+00:00 app[web.1]: Hash: fad1ddf0709d9e61457e
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683131+00:00 app[web.1]: Version: webpack 3.11.0
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683133+00:00 app[web.1]: Time: 2336ms
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683140+00:00 app[web.1]:    Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683149+00:00 app[web.1]:   [10] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683142+00:00 app[web.1]: index.js  1.08 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683147+00:00 app[web.1]:    [2] ./node_modules/react/index.js 190 bytes {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683148+00:00 app[web.1]:    [5] (webpack)/hot/log.js 1.04 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683152+00:00 app[web.1]:   [18] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./main.js 52 bytes {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683154+00:00 app[web.1]:   [19] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 7.91 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683155+00:00 app[web.1]:   [20] ./node_modules/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683170+00:00 app[web.1]:     + 41 hidden modules
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683166+00:00 app[web.1]:   [41] ./main.js 480 bytes {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683158+00:00 app[web.1]:   [29] ./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 7.86 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683175+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack: Compiled successfully.
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683159+00:00 app[web.1]:   [30] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.08 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683169+00:00 app[web.1]:   [54] ./components/App.js 2.44 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683160+00:00 app[web.1]:   [32] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.67 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683161+00:00 app[web.1]:   [37] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683162+00:00 app[web.1]:   [39] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.61 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683164+00:00 app[web.1]:   [40] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.31 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:48:01.683168+00:00 app[web.1]:   [45] ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 1.36 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:48:56.915037+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-02-14T14:48:56.915096+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-02-14T14:48:57.007714+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-02-14T14:48:57.023034+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-02-14T14:48:57.026046+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-02-14T14:49:00.597853+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-02-14T14:49:02.550597+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-02-14T14:49:02.550622+00:00 app[web.1]: > star-quizes-client@1.0.0 start /app
2018-02-14T14:49:02.550626+00:00 app[web.1]: > webpack-dev-server --hot
2018-02-14T14:49:02.550628+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-02-14T14:49:03.916803+00:00 app[web.1]: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
2018-02-14T14:49:03.917353+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack output is served from /
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989275+00:00 app[web.1]: Hash: fad1ddf0709d9e61457e
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989282+00:00 app[web.1]: Version: webpack 3.11.0
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989284+00:00 app[web.1]: Time: 2083ms
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989286+00:00 app[web.1]:    Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989288+00:00 app[web.1]: index.js  1.08 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989290+00:00 app[web.1]:    [2] ./node_modules/react/index.js 190 bytes {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989292+00:00 app[web.1]:    [5] (webpack)/hot/log.js 1.04 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989293+00:00 app[web.1]:   [10] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989295+00:00 app[web.1]:   [18] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./main.js 52 bytes {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989297+00:00 app[web.1]:   [19] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 7.91 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989299+00:00 app[web.1]:   [20] ./node_modules/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989300+00:00 app[web.1]:   [29] ./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 7.86 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989302+00:00 app[web.1]:   [30] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.08 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989303+00:00 app[web.1]:   [32] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.67 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989304+00:00 app[web.1]:   [37] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989305+00:00 app[web.1]:   [39] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.61 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989306+00:00 app[web.1]:   [40] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.31 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989308+00:00 app[web.1]:   [41] ./main.js 480 bytes {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989309+00:00 app[web.1]:   [45] ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 1.36 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989310+00:00 app[web.1]:   [54] ./components/App.js 2.44 kB {0} [built]
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989311+00:00 app[web.1]:     + 41 hidden modules
2018-02-14T14:49:05.989318+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack: Compiled successfully.
2018-02-14T14:49:32.334810+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=star-quizes.herokuapp.com request_id=d3e576fb-90c1-4c12-859e-c66cc92f54b7 fwd="73.92.104.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-14T14:50:01.107846+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-02-14T14:50:01.107999+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-02-14T14:50:01.195819+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-02-14T14:50:01.207788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-02-14T14:50:02.591388+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=star-quizes.herokuapp.com request_id=3362ec47-083b-414c-9fbb-c5f69eca2703 fwd="73.92.104.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-14T14:50:03.351220+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=star-quizes.herokuapp.com request_id=2ce90afe-1e8b-4e7c-970c-bc66e4ae2aac fwd="73.92.104.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-14T14:50:02.647818+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=star-quizes.herokuapp.com request_id=b3c38bd2-b1c9-4854-85c3-0a2e34a6dea3 fwd="73.92.104.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-14T14:55:45.117503+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=star-quizes.herokuapp.com request_id=f790117a-1954-45cc-81c4-a03111f269ec fwd="73.92.104.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-14T14:55:45.370332+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=star-quizes.herokuapp.com request_id=7b3f485d-95ed-4a8e-b223-d6130c594b16 fwd="73.92.104.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
Johns-MacBook-Pro:star-quizes-client johnseabolt$
```

Here is my webpack config file:

```
var config = {
    entry: './main.js', // entry point
    output: {
          filename: 'index.js', // place where bundled app will be served
       },
    devServer: {
          inline: true, // autorefresh
          port: 8080 // development port server
       },
    module: {
          loaders: [
             {
                test: /\.jsx?$/, // search for js files 
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react'] // use es2015 and react
             }
          }
       ]
    }
 }
 module.exports = config;
```

Again, that's copy-pasted from the tutorial. But something isn't going right.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "star-quizes-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1", 
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  }
}
```

The app took a good two minutes to deploy, which may be a clue? Normally with create-react-app things deploy in 15 seconds on my computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku + node.js error (Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that question. This is a React app. It doesn't have a server..

Comment: When you run the app locally, do you start a server?