# How do I deploy node app to heroku without using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, heroku, heroku-api

I deployed my node.js app successfully to heroku however when I accessed the site there was an error saying 
`"Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch"`

my code is

```
var router = require("./router.js");

// Create a web server
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  router.home(request, response);
  router.user(request, response);
}).listen(1337);
console.log("Sever running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/");
```

I figured it has something to do with the port. There was a post similar to my problem [Heroku + node.js error (Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of)
but their solutions were based on Express. I didn't use express for my app.
Is there any other way to not set the port to a fixed number?

Comment: Try to bind to `process.env.PORT` rather than port 1337. PORT is an environment variable that Heroku sets for you.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if you use `express` or not. Herouku binds a port for you in the `process.env.PORT` environment variable. You need to use that like so:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337
```

Then use `.listen(port)`
Make sure you're connecting to the correct port in your browser (log the port to console to be sure)