# Heroku App Only Working On Local Machine

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, heroku, localhost

Have something really odd going on with Heroku.

I have an application build in React/JS/Node with Mongo.

If I pull up the link to my app on my local machine: https://obscure-crag-61417.herokuapp.com/, I can see a version of my website, but it is not updating for any changes that I push to Heroku.

Even more strange, is that on a non-local machine, if i visit the aforementioned link, I get the boilerplate 'Express' page.

I've tried clearing the cache, exiting browsers on both PC's but same old story.

I have the MongoDB config set in Heroku.

Not sure what could be going on here.

Any ideas?

PS--here's my code:  https://github.com/pythoncreate/twit-stocks

Answer (score 0):

Okay i figured this one out.  I'm pretty sure it was how I was setting the ports on the backend.  Heroku has some specific rules about this:

[Heroku + node.js error (Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of)