# getting a 503 error when uploading to heroku with my nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have been struggling to get my app loaded to heroku for the past couple of days.  I get over one hurdle and then meet another.  Now I am getting a the following error.

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service  Unavailable) /favicon.ico
```

On the logs I am getting these error messages.

```
2018-04-11T08:13:48.238214+00:00 app[web.1]: > rock-paper-scissors@1.0.0 start  /app
2018-04-11T08:13:48.331598+00:00 app[web.1]: Server has started.
2018-04-11T08:13:48.238216+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-04-11T08:13:48.238198+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-04-11T08:14:46.646952+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to   crashed
2018-04-11T08:14:46.571274+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) ->    Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-04-11T08:14:46.629369+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-04-11T09:38:48.218885+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=brianpat-rock-paper-scissors.herokuapp.com request_id=0db40b3c-c918-4a3d-9a4d-f3a5fcf69bc8 fwd="94.174.32.117" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-04-11T09:38:48.541351+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=brianpat-rock-paper-scissors.herokuapp.com request_id=ecf56ae7-84e6-43a0-9a77-3e9f9a7f538f fwd="94.174.32.117" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Yesterday I was getting a Method not Allowed error and now I am not sure if it has moved on or not.  Not sure if this is my end or whether this is a maintenance issue with heroku?  Possibly my end. I have tried looking for the same error on Stackoverflow but they have not proved helpful.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first thing I'd try is to either upload a `favicon.ico` file (to your public folder, I guess) or to remove the reference from the index view.

Comment: Could that be anything? I have converted some of the png files in the app to .ico.  How do I know if there is a reference to it in the index.html file ?

Comment: Open the index file and check the `<head>` for a `<link rel="icon">` line that references `favicon.ico`. Remove it.

Comment: There is no link to favicon.ico in the index.html page. I have added one but it does not show up locally. ```<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="image/favicon.ico">```

Comment: The server is trying to load `/favicon.ico` because it is requested by the browser. For some reason your app crashes while doing that, instead of replying with a 404 Not found error. Without seeing your app's source code, all we can do is guess wildly.

Comment: Is there a way for me to show you my source code?

Comment: You can put relevant parts in the question, or put it on github. Btw, the website also tries to load `./public/main.js` which does result in a 404 error.

Comment: I will update and give you the link to my github.

Comment: here is the link https://github.com/amidabrian51/Rock_Paper_Scissors

Comment: I'll take a look

Comment: Alright, the main problem is your way of serving files. While you do catch 404 errors, a better way is to not rely on `try/catch` to do so. In this case, `fs.exists()` is a much better solution. An even better solution though is to use an existing solution like `express` to serve your files. Btw, I'm pretty sure that `/favicon.ico` is requested by the browser; it wants to put it in the tab so just goes ahead and requests it.

Comment: So what do you suggest that I do now? If you don’t mind me asking.

Comment: You can `npm install http-server` and use `require("http-server").createServer().listen(3000);` in your `index.js`. It'll serve the `public` folder by default.

Comment: I am now getting the following error ```brianpat-rock-paper-scissors.herokuapp.com didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE```

Comment: It is now giving me the following in the logs ```at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=brianpat-rock-paper-scissors.herokuapp.com request_id=71e45c5c-b252-4037-bfb0-d1443534ec3d fwd="94.174.32.117" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https```

Comment: Here's what worked for me: `require("http-server").createServer().listen(process.env.PORT);`, then on heroku, under Settings -> Config Variables, add `PORT`: `8080` It's online here: https://rps-test-so.herokuapp.com/ (the key isn't using a variable but the proper port, I guess)

Comment: I am now getting the following error ``
brianpat-rock-paper-scissors.git Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)``  ARRRGH

Comment: It worked!  Thank you very much Chris G.  Can you put your answer above and I will upvote it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku + node.js error (Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of)