# Connecting Mongoose to MLab H10 503

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mlab

I'm getting an H10 error with my node app on Heroku. It was working fine until I added Google analytics to my EJS files. My env port is set fine, the only other thing I think it could be is my connection to my MongoDB database on MLab...

Here's the app file:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
router = express.Router(),
ejs = require('ejs'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
passport = require('passport'),
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
flash = require('connect-flash'),
methodOverride = require('method-override'),
Post = require('./models/post'),
helmet = require('helmet'),
Comment = require("./models/comment"),
Email = require("./ignore/email"),
Raph = require("./ignore/raphuser"),
User = require('./models/user'),
nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
postRoutes = require('./routes/posts');


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


app.use('/api/posts', postRoutes);
app.use(helmet());
app.use(flash());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// then my routes

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

And also my connection to MLab:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://myusername:mypassword@ds147390.mlab.com:47390/dbname");

mongoose.Promise = Promise;
```

module.exports.Post = require('./post');

Comment: Can you show the error message and also add a callback console.log to your mongoose connect function?

Comment: yep two secs.....

Comment: How would I do the callback properly? I'm doing this to try and getting work, but getting an unhandled error back: mongoose.connect("mongodb://user:pw@ds147390.mlab.com:47390/personal_blog_posts", function(error, db){
    if (error) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        return db;
    }
});

Comment: `var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('Connected to database was successful!')
});`

Comment: Hi I got it going, here's the error message 2018-09-27T21:23:05.656321+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.raphael-hetherington.com request_id=ee2401bb-8fdf-4566-bcee-01abbc58bf63 fwd="37.228.225.172" dyno= connect= service= status=503bytes= protocol=http
2018-09-27T21:23:11.380853+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.raphael-hetherington.com request_id=72dfebe9-82ae-46c0-b493-1c85ccc63df6 fwd="66.85.140.125" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http

Comment: From what I see the error is about a missing favicon file. Do you have a favicon file in the root directory?

Comment: there is no problem when I run it on a local server - it connets to mlab fine... there's something causing the issue when I push to heroku

Comment: Can you try `heroku restart`

Comment: the favicon is in my img directory in the public folder, which is given a relative path because I set it in the app.js

Comment: heroku restart didn't work :(

Comment: This may be a duplicated question, check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of

Comment: I've got my port set like this:

Comment: var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    
  app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", function(){
    console.log('app is running on port: ', port);
  });

Comment: thanks for the help - I think it is to do with the ports...