# How to configure Postgres on Heroku for my .net core web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, heroku-postgres

I have successfully deployed a .net core web API on Heroku, but the app fails to launch. When I attempt to run the app, I get the error below:
**Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch**

Here is the connection string my .net core code

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DromiContext": "User=user;Password=password;Host=host;Port=5432;Database=database;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;"
```

}

*Related Question*
[Heroku + node.js error (Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a couple minute to review [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is missing a good amount of crucial information. Please try adding tags for the relevant frameworks/languages you're using and edit your question to include helpful information like the application code that starts your webserver and anything else that might be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  app was not configured to run migration automatically. After it was updated

`

```
using (var serviceScope = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DromiContext>();
                context.Database.Migrate();
            }
```

`

The error disappeared