# Heroku | Change app to a worker app rather than web

Tags: heroku

I'm using Heroku Scheduler to run a few apps each night. I believe they are what Heroku would call a "worker apps" because they run for about 2 hours each and only need to run once per day. That said, I can't figure out how to change them from being web apps to worker apps?

For context, I'm using the free tier of Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a file called Procfile in your root.

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44122238/12020295

So, change your `Procfile` to read (with your specific command filled in):

`worker: node index.js`

and then also run on CLI:

`$ heroku scale worker=1`