# heroku removing non dev dependences

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, next.js

i have a next.js app working fine on my pc  when i push to heroku the build succeeds  but inside server.js i get this error i catched the error using heroku logs --tail

```
2021-07-05T02:45:46.882384+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
2021-07-05T02:45:46.882607+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
2021-07-05T02:45:47.113165+00:00 app[web.1]: info  - Loaded env from /app/.env
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176310+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:41) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'react-dom/server'
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176361+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176363+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176364+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176364+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176365+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176365+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176366+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176366+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176367+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176367+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:1:136)
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176368+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176368+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176369+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176369+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176369+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176370+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176396+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:41) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
2021-07-05T02:45:47.176467+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:41) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715226+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:41) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'react-dom/server'
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715247+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715248+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715248+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715249+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715249+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715250+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715253+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.mod._resolveFilename (/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-hook.js:4:1855)
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715254+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715254+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715254+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715255+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:1:136)
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715255+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715256+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715256+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715256+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
2021-07-05T02:45:49.715372+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:41) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
2021-07-05T02:45:49.726924+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

i dont understand what's happening i searched a lot but found no solution please help thanks.

EDIT: i deployed it on vercel without custom server and got no issues i found out heroku removes some packages even thou i haven't setup any dev dependencies
why is heroku removing my dependencies?:

```
...

remote:
remote:        λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
remote:        ○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
remote:        ●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
remote:           (ISR)     incremental static regeneration (uses revalidate in getStaticProps)
remote:
remote:
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        - node_modules
remote:
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        removed 26 packages and audited 835 packages in 7.315s
remote:
remote:        77 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 82M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v13
remote:        https://.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/.git
   4412d3e..9715241  main -> main
```

later when visiting my-website/admin i got this  error because the dependences were removed:

```
2021-07-05T02:54:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-07-05T02:54:22.718465+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-07-05T02:54:25.266226+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-07-05T02:54:25.266244+00:00 app[web.1]: > shop-demo@0.1.0 prestart /app
2021-07-05T02:54:25.266244+00:00 app[web.1]: > next build
2021-07-05T02:54:25.266244+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-07-05T02:54:25.378209+00:00 app[web.1]: The module 'react-dom' was not found. Next.js requires that you include it in 'dependencies' of your 'package.json'. To add it, run 'npm install react-dom'
2021-07-05T02:54:26.139286+00:00 app[web.1]: info  - Loaded env from /app/.env
2021-07-05T02:54:27.623400+00:00 app[web.1]: info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
2021-07-05T02:54:28.812338+00:00 app[web.1]: Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
2021-07-05T02:54:28.812470+00:00 app[web.1]: This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
2021-07-05T02:54:28.812537+00:00 app[web.1]: You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
2021-07-05T02:54:28.812604+00:00 app[web.1]: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
2021-07-05T02:54:28.812672+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-07-05T02:54:28.872979+00:00 app[web.1]: info  - Checking validity of types...
2021-07-05T02:54:36.205615+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to compile.
2021-07-05T02:54:36.205624+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-07-05T02:54:36.206601+00:00 app[web.1]: ./components/admin.tsx:4:24
2021-07-05T02:54:36.206616+00:00 app[web.1]: Type error: Cannot find module '@material-ui/core/Typography' or its corresponding type declarations.
2021-07-05T02:54:36.206617+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-07-05T02:54:36.206623+00:00 app[web.1]:   2 | import { DataGrid, GridRowsProp, GridColDef } from "@material-ui/data-grid";
2021-07-05T02:54:36.206623+00:00 app[web.1]:   3 | import { Fragment } from "react";
2021-07-05T02:54:36.206625+00:00 app[web.1]: > 4 | import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
2021-07-05T02:54:36.206628+00:00 app[web.1]:     |                        ^
2021-07-05T02:54:36.206628+00:00 app[web.1]:   5 | import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
2021-07-05T02:54:36.206629+00:00 app[web.1]:   6 | import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
2021-07-05T02:54:36.206629+00:00 app[web.1]:   7 | import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
2021-07-05T02:54:36.273027+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-07-05T02:54:36.273426+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-07-05T02:54:36.282867+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! shop-demo@0.1.0 prestart: `next build`
2021-07-05T02:54:36.283033+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-07-05T02:54:36.283306+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-07-05T02:54:36.283519+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the shop-demo@0.1.0 prestart script.
2021-07-05T02:54:36.283716+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-07-05T02:54:36.290841+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-07-05T02:54:36.291071+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-07-05T02:54:36.291188+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-07-05T02_54_36_284Z-debug.log
2021-07-05T02:54:36.354248+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-07-05T02:54:36.421564+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-07-05
```

Comment: Have you tried deploying your NextJS app to Vercel? https://vercel.com/

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera no i'm using custom server and vercel doesn't support custom server i'll try deploying without the server and see what happen

Comment: did you run ``npm install``?

Comment: "i found out heroku removes some packages even thou i haven't setup any dev dependencies"—please [edit] your question and show us your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a weird bug! in my custom server using process.env.PORT fixed the problem

and without custom server you have to change the start script to:

```
"start": "next start -p $PORT"
```

More info: [Heroku + node.js error (Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of)