# heroku app is deployed but when i try to visit the app it gives following errors when i use heroku logs --tail

Tags: heroku

this is the error logs im getting after deploying heroku app, i am a newbie this is what i got got after deploying my first app on heroku, what changes should i make so that the app works fine                                                                      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
heroku logs --tail
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.59.0.
2021-08-28T16:52:12.798078+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user ameyv.chavan22@gmail.com
2021-08-28T16:52:12.798078+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user ameyv.chavan22@gmail.com
2021-08-28T16:52:13.326358+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user ameyv.chavan22@gmail.com
2021-08-28T16:52:13.326358+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user ameyv.chavan22@gmail.com
2021-08-28T17:07:25.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ameyv.chavan22@gmail.com
2021-08-28T17:07:44.382543+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 51b4fd44 by user ameyv.chavan22@gmail.com
2021-08-28T17:07:44.382543+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user ameyv.chavan22@gmail.com
2021-08-28T17:07:44.395803+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user ameyv.chavan22@gmail.com
2021-08-28T17:07:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-08-28T17:07:46.721328+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-08-28T17:07:49.277716+00:00 app[web.1]: Server has started sucessfully
2021-08-28T17:08:47.102190+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-08-28T17:08:47.397400+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-08-28T17:08:47.487625+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-08-28T17:08:47.554163+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-08-28T17:08:47.557513+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-08-28T17:08:49.459570+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-08-28T17:08:51.872078+00:00 app[web.1]: Server has started sucessfully
2021-08-28T17:09:28.638661+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=d622853d-02a9-4664-9ba6-01fd0a3c7791 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:09:50.122275+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-08-28T17:09:50.166954+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-08-28T17:09:50.240786+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-08-28T17:09:50.304939+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-08-28T17:12:30.299513+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=b5657585-53d9-467f-90f2-7053b4c770f6 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:12:30.976544+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=455a1136-3a5a-43dd-bbef-6c809f3c6ced fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:16:16.127810+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=01349493-0c9a-435a-a9b4-21c71af295e5 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:16:16.807523+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=35b3de1c-64ec-4d74-996d-d256ec864b8c fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:16:19.836898+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=445637c1-a389-47c0-b1ee-ec2e95508572 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:16:20.438846+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=5c781e31-1c26-4508-9920-af20fe4ccfb3 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:18:55.491494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=3912f43a-afce-416f-986d-97258ac4f0b4 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:18:56.130249+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=0d6492be-a6b8-43c1-ac6e-d5aa25f2536d fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:21:18.508637+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=f835513d-5242-46bd-ad55-ce015b6ced55 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:21:19.069729+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=59e9a681-cb4b-4445-9792-5e29083bd065 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:24:07.908568+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=999c69d2-dab5-4b27-b348-b42912a55adb fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:24:08.713831+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=0fe2d380-dfc8-4fc0-ae62-6df201ea17c2 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:24:23.220829+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=5d3d9f3a-b876-4616-a013-687154d34c7c fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:24:23.802914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=fbdcba90-0e2e-4d3e-b03d-78e9583c541f fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:25:15.498295+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=b4eaa392-a085-4421-b488-8fbedb21f6a8 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:25:16.084729+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=a823d1b5-2a65-4379-8c53-32d3526da61e fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:26:12.679293+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=9a4d7651-6be5-4726-bc37-bd27f1aa2671 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:28:50.332848+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=c9643b0c-3c4a-48ec-88f0-7edd4ffde749 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:28:51.598599+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=4bbf0f47-b587-4e16-b81b-4fd01aeaf319 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:29:12.822863+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=7f80fda0-a82c-4dd7-8dde-65da5e2a0d2a fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:32:44.728204+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=07a9e966-c427-461b-839f-b5951853ade8 fwd="106.210.137.144" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:32:46.288092+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=6a038fc4-32b5-4723-b4f7-68635bbb57f0 fwd="106.210.137.144" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:33:13.537857+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=f5519591-e2f1-4ddf-a0f1-d2646976c5b4 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:34:32.118895+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=15c8a3d0-e609-4715-8ca7-97692ef9a640 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:34:32.520189+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=bb62bf8f-ab53-4a87-acc7-4aa50d34b538 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:38:28.848851+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by user ameyv.chavan22@gmail.com2021-08-28T17:38:32.211906+00:00 heroku[run.9104]: Awaiting client
2021-08-28T17:38:32.244364+00:00 heroku[run.9104]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2021-08-28T17:38:32.257202+00:00 heroku[run.9104]: State changed from starting to up
2021-08-28T17:38:36.411213+00:00 heroku[run.9104]: Process exited with status 127
2021-08-28T17:38:36.531538+00:00 heroku[run.9104]: State changed from up to complete
2021-08-28T17:38:45.459967+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=c2eda213-aeb7-4d03-8d76-d2338b9998e3 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:38:46.030323+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=9b44b49f-7a49-45a9-9890-cc867d52dd5d fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:39:03.564349+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-08-28T17:39:06.396407+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-08-28T17:39:09.174472+00:00 app[web.1]: Server has started sucessfully
2021-08-28T17:40:06.563076+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-08-28T17:40:06.594419+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-08-28T17:40:06.663526+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-08-28T17:40:06.726895+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-08-28T17:40:06.779059+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-08-28T17:40:09.352690+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-08-28T17:40:11.218822+00:00 app[web.1]: Server has started sucessfully
2021-08-28T17:40:26.676919+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=e06256e4-8dc7-429d-8dc7-56caf54c554f fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:40:45.448578+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=624ac3dc-c811-400e-9e2b-e4b38c92f6eb fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:41:09.489490+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-08-28T17:41:09.534167+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-08-28T17:41:09.601989+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-08-28T17:41:09.666399+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-08-28T17:41:10.246586+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=828286a4-06a5-4cac-a203-09f8494ee261 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:41:10.809343+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=e39fd91d-6278-4388-86b8-68612e9cfeef fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-28T17:41:11.102099+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-reaches-76755.herokuapp.com request_id=9ed0f0a8-f393-4e8b-ab68-c4650c167f15 fwd="103.163.188.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku + node.js error (Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue as this.

If you are using node js:

Wrong:

```
web : npm run start
```

(Remove the space after `web:`)

Correct:

```
web:npm run start
```

I think the Heroku website has a space after `web:` in its instructions but it actually leads the app to crash.