# Error after deploying (Applicaton error) on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

### Intro

I had made a Login form.

I had deployed the frontend on Netlify [here](https://61e7c30ba3c9d58a9fe302e2--nifty-goldwasser-573c0f.netlify.app/login) and the backend on Heroku [here](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/my-notebook-mohit/logs).
This is my backend logs https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/my-notebook-mohit/logs

My index.js is

```
const connectToMongo = require('./db');
const express = require('express');


connectToMongo();
var cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
const port = 5000

//to use req body 
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

//Available routes
app.use('/api/auth',require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/api/notes',require('./routes/notes'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port , () => {
  console.log(`my-notebook backend listening at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || port}`)
})
```

LoginPage.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import imgpath from "../assets/notepic.jpg";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const Login = (props) => {
  let history = useHistory();

  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setCredentials({ ...credentials, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    //input mei value typed ho sake,jaise jaise value change ho vese-vese note me set ho jaye
  };

  const goToSignup = () => {
    history.push("/signup");
  };
  
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: credentials.email,
        password: credentials.password,
      }),
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    if (json.success === true) {
      //storing the authtoken
      localStorage.setItem("token", json.authToken);
      props.showAlert("User logged in successfully", "info");
      history.push("/");
    } else {
      props.showAlert("invalid Credentials", "danger");
    }
    console.log(json);
  };

  return (
   .....
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="login-form">
           .....
           ....
   </form>
  ...
  ...

};

export default Login;
```

### Problem I facing

When I make a POST request on the login button from **frontend deployed on Netlify**, it goes to `http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login` as it makes the fetch request there only , hence shows error.

[error ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K41tE.jpg)

### What I think?

The reason I could think is that Heroku is dynamically assigning the **any other port i.e. 49004 when I check from Heroku Logs** and my request is sent over **port 5000**.

**How do I add the dynamic port to the fetch request I made?**

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code, you've used `const port = 5000` in your nodejs backend.

This must be replaced with `const port = process.env.PORT || 5000`

This is because heroku dynamically assigns a port number to the running application when it's deployed, so you can't set the port to a fixed number.

Comment: Ya I have seen it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of

Comment: are you still facing the problem after changing `const port`?

Comment: But Still I am getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` while making any post request. Youc an check the changes I made in the last 2 commits here https://github.com/mohitm15/my-notebook/commits/master/backend/index.js

Comment: provide a screenshot of the error

Comment: already thee, i had figured out the problem and changing the whole question here, since I can not post another for 90 min due to my less rputation

Comment: change `http://localhost:5000` on the frontend to the new heroku url

Comment: I tried to use `fetch(`https://my-notebook-mohit.herokuapp.com:${port}/api/auth/login`, {...` where port=process.env.PORT 

but it shows `Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL from https://my-notebook-mohit.herokuapp.com:undefined/api/auth/login`


You can check the last two commit here https://github.com/mohitm15/my-notebook/commits/master

Comment: replace it with `fetch("https://my-notebook-mohit.herokuapp.com/api/auth/login" , {`

The heroku url does not require the port to be listed while fetching, heroku takes care of that