# Why i am getting application error in heroku while deploy the project in node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, application-error

[my index.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY2d3.png)

[error in heroku i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoJUx.png)

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const res = require('express/lib/response');
const app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

require('/routes/dialogFlowRoutes')(app);
var PORT =process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT,()=>{
console.log('App is runing on port ${PORT}');
});
```

i am new to it but i am getting error in heroku when i deploy my first app i don't know  much about errors in it now so cant able to figure out the error i am getting anyone can help me out it will be grateful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku + node.js error (Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of) also specify host as 0.0.0.0 look at not accepted answers

Comment: thank you i solve it i just forget to again push the code to heroku