# Heroku / React / Docusaurus - Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: reactjs, heroku, docusaurus

When deploying a fairly vanilla docusaurus (React package) to Heroku, I cannot seem to build it and access it...

I get these errors:

```
2022-07-04T07:57:45.906918+00:00 app[web.1]: ✔ Client: Compiled successfully in 235.87ms
2022-07-04T07:57:45.909887+00:00 app[web.1]: client (webpack 5.72.0) compiled successfully
2022-07-04T07:58:32.529800+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-07-04T07:58:32.569851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-07-04T07:58:32.590954+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2022-07-04T07:58:32.775949+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2022-07-04T07:58:32.816768+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I have looked into this, [most of the time people say that there is a binding error with Heroku ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of). I don't really know what that means to be honest, but in any case, I don't understand because this is a frontend app and does not (AFAIK) involve Node js. It's a simple web app, not sure why it can't just compile...as such there is nowhere for me to specify a port anyway with a React app as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a vanilla-ish Docusaurus project, you can host it on Heroku by including the following in your `Procfile`. You may also need to set the buildpack to be `heroku/nodejs`, but Heroku should auto-discover the project type for you.

```
web: npm run serve -- -p $PORT
```

#### Why this Works

`npm run serve` runs `docusaurus serve` "under the hood" which starts a small Node process that serves the static files under the `build` directory. I assume Heroku is already correctly building your Docusaurus site - which it should since the `nodejs` buildpack runs `npm run build` by default if present.

This altogether will serve your project correctly so Heroku's routing can correctly bind to it. The `-p $PORT` specifies that we want to run the Docusaurus server at the port denoted by Heroku, and the `--` is an `npm` argument separator where anything after the `--` is passed along to the underlying command being run.

Comment: Thank you so much - this worked perfectly, and you explained why it works. Thanks!