# Hosting quart app on heroku: receiving an Error R10 (Boot timeout) despite specifying host and port in app.run()

Tags: python, heroku, quart, hypercorn

I'm trying to deploy a Quart web app on Heroku, but I'm getting the infamous "Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch".

My current Procfile: `web: hypercorn asgi:app`

The file to run my Quart app (asgi.py):

```
import os
from app.main import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 8000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Whether, I specify the port and host in app.run() or not, the app works locally but not remotely.

I have also tried setting up the Procfile as `web: hypercorn -b 0.0.0.0$PORT asgi:app` and not specifying the port or host in asgi.py. This breaks the app both locally and remotely.

I feel as though I have exhausted the solutions that worked for everyone else, so any other ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may [find this answer useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of).

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED! The issues local were due to needing a Procfile.windows for local development and running `heroku local web -f Procfile.windows` for local testing.

My issue with testing the deployed app was just a few characters. I removed any of the port and host specification in asgi.py and changed my procfile to `web: hypercorn asgi:app --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT`. `-b` was not able to be used. I needed both dashes and to spell out the word "bind".