# Serving static files in Express without an IP adress

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express

I have the following code, for example, throughout my template files:

`<link href="http://localhost:3000/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

This forces me to change the IP address from `http://localhost:3000` to the web server IP address whenever I launch the website. As you can imagine, there are a lot of template files for the whole site. I have written scripts that can search-and-replace the IP instances in the project's template files and I'd like to avoid that if I can.

I'd like to keep the following format:

`<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Notice it is independent of the origin. I'd hope there was middlewear that Express could use the current location of the server to serve the files.

I am currently using this code in my `server.js` file:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname ,'/v1/public/')));`

And works great if I specify the host in the template files. I haven't found any resources online that do what I want to do easily.

Comment: Why not just use absolute paths?

Comment: I think you want to set the port differently? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17004592/3662110

Comment: @SLaks As stated in the post, I'd have to manually or write a script to autonomously replace the absolute path when I launch the server.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I am not having issues related to the port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the header is a template file, why don't you pass the full url as a variable to the template? You can construct the url at app level by something like this:

```
var baseUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');
```

and pass `baseUrl` to your header template and prefix the paths at run-time.

Comment: This solution is practical and exceptionally effective. 

**edit:** For future developers: `req.get('host')` also includes the port and colon in the url returned string. No need to append it. Use exactly as Arbel prescribed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
href="http://localhost:3000/v1/public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
```

or relative:

```
href="./v1/public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
```

Your static folder is the folder path where the static resources will be served.