# Heroku errors while deploying Node.js application

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to run a Node.js application on Heroku, but am seeing R10 and H10 errors.

Here are the Heroku logs:

(Note: in my Heroku logs I came accross this **gitAccess@0.0.0 start /app**
should it be app.js but I have declared it properly in package.json.)

```
 1. C:\project\gitAccess>heroku logs                                    


C:\project\gitAccess>heroku logs
2016-09-26T15:17:46.982704+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by sacdh2@gmail
.com
2016-09-26T15:17:46.982704+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by sacdh2@gmail.com

2016-09-26T15:19:39.879219+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by sacdh2@gmail.com

2016-09-26T15:19:39.879734+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 14b360e by sacdh2@gmail.com

2016-09-26T15:19:39.879872+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by sacdh2@gmail
.com
2016-09-26T15:19:40.380795+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started

2016-09-26T15:19:40.380800+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finishe
d
2016-09-26T15:19:41.542552+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `n
pm start`
2016-09-26T15:19:43.849669+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-26T15:19:43.849685+00:00 app[web.1]: > gitAccess@0.0.0 start /app
2016-09-26T15:19:43.849687+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-26T15:19:43.849686+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./app
2016-09-26T15:20:41.633728+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web
process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-09-26T15:20:41.633728+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-09-26T15:20:41.800843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-09-26T15:20:41.802015+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2016-09-26T15:20:41.745945+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-09-26T15:20:43.458207+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `n
pm start`
2016-09-26T15:20:46.191870+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-26T15:20:46.191888+00:00 app[web.1]: > gitAccess@0.0.0 start /app
2016-09-26T15:20:46.191889+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./app
2016-09-26T15:20:46.191890+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-26T15:21:44.040560+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web
process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-09-26T15:21:44.040699+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-09-26T15:21:44.140816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-09-26T15:21:44.129449+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-09-26T15:21:46.709334+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=radiant-cliffs-71522.herokuapp.com request_id=fe3
cf7f7-b223-4f21-b7a4-d4f37af7dac6 fwd="115.99.170.213" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes=
2016-09-26T15:21:49.464884+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=radiant-cliffs-71522.herokuapp.com req
uest_id=6cc6cee2-36f7-40e1-a156-17651ad00667 fwd="115.99.170.213" dyno= connect=
 service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-26T15:23:52.090333+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=radiant-cliffs-71522.herokuapp.com request_id=6ba
f1018-77bb-45be-8780-6fd31e381c80 fwd="115.99.170.213" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes=
2016-09-26T15:23:53.780265+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=radiant-cliffs-71522.herokuapp.com req
uest_id=f2db6452-348a-4446-8b2b-aecfd8a2f457 fwd="115.99.170.213" dyno= connect=
 service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-26T15:30:51.296851+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 60e8c27 by sacdh2@gmail.com

2016-09-26T15:30:51.296938+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by sacdh2@gmail
.com
2016-09-26T15:30:51.571152+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started

2016-09-26T15:30:51.571161+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finishe
d
2016-09-26T15:30:51.922270+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2016-09-26T15:30:53.138220+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `:
 node app.js`
2016-09-26T15:30:55.291163+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-09-26T15:30:55.308919+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-09-26T15:31:27.148553+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=radiant-cliffs-71522.herokuapp.com request_id=a93
fb912-7cc4-4413-871a-33021bf66eef fwd="115.99.170.213" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes=
2016-09-26T15:31:28.304843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=radiant-cliffs-71522.herokuapp.com req
uest_id=df2015c6-e9e3-432e-8d11-55169d7e77b3 fwd="115.99.170.213" dyno= connect=
 service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-26T15:31:36.454736+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=radiant-cliffs-71522.herokuapp.com request_id=597
268c2-6d18-425b-aebc-2cfe6051d308 fwd="115.99.170.213" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes=
2016-09-26T15:31:36.774936+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=radiant-cliffs-71522.herokuapp.com req
uest_id=438dd5e0-bcb6-4b11-82b9-a464d8cef5c0 fwd="115.99.170.213" dyno= connect=
 service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-26T15:32:02.283353+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=radiant-cliffs-71522.herokuapp.com request_id=514
eb7a4-904c-4364-ad93-003282019db5 fwd="115.99.170.213" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes=
2016-09-26T15:32:04.043738+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=radiant-cliffs-71522.herokuapp.com req
uest_id=5ccfecca-0f7a-4b0c-a884-0f7709821c74 fwd="115.99.170.213" dyno= connect=
 service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-26T15:36:25.550391+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 4c1c8b7 by sacdh2@gmail.com

2016-09-26T15:36:25.550391+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by sacdh2@gmail
.com
2016-09-26T15:36:25.941408+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started

2016-09-26T15:36:25.941417+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finishe
d
2016-09-26T15:36:27.272615+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2016-09-26T15:36:28.295815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `:
 node app.js`
2016-09-26T15:36:30.323543+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-09-26T15:36:30.339915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-09-26T15:36:30.341235+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2016-09-26T15:36:31.474676+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `:
 node app.js`
2016-09-26T15:36:33.785629+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-09-26T15:36:33.815017+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-09-26T15:36:34.719231+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=radiant-cliffs-71522.herokuapp.com request_id=6d6
f9e90-298c-4b08-aa57-6f10559e4c55 fwd="115.99.170.213" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes=
2016-09-26T15:36:36.389957+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2016-09-26T15:36:36.438156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/browserconfig.xml" host=radiant-cliffs-71522.herokuapp.c
om request_id=8eed6f7f-ee60-416e-baae-773808cdc054 fwd="115.99.170.213" dyno= co
nnect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-26T15:37:11.368116+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=radiant-cliffs-71522.herokuapp.com request_id=68c
938b2-9458-4fcb-b9ce-7ebe3a494c04 fwd="115.99.170.213" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes=
2016-09-26T15:38:56.055760+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=radiant-cliffs-71522.herokuapp.com request_id=332
3e9fa-8b2c-4a25-9300-b84dcde617b4 fwd="115.99.170.213" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes=
2016-09-26T15:39:19.197478+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=radiant-cliffs-71522.herokuapp.com request_id=d26
5c548-ba8d-4c75-8c4b-93f49f80da7e fwd="115.99.170.213" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes=
2016-09-26T15:39:32.608048+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 

C:\project\gitAccess>
```

My app.Js file looks like this

```
    var https = require("https");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var path         = require('path');

var routes = require('./server');

// setting up middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cookieParser());
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});

module.exports = app;
```

and this is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "gitAccess",
  "version": "v4.2.4",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.4.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "github": "^3.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.15.1",
    "parse-github-url": "^0.3.2"
  },
  "engines" :{
    "node" : "0.12.7"
  }
}
```

also I have set up my Procfile as      **web : node app.js**
Where can I be going wrong.

Edit : My server.Js files

```
    var https = require("https");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var gh = require('parse-github-url'); // use to break the url user provides into various parts
var moment = require('moment'); // for Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in JavaScript.
var router = express.Router();
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var _ = require('underscore-node');

router.post('/click', function(req, res){
    var url = gh(req.body.url);
    var userName = url.owner;
    var repo = url.name;
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var pastDay = moment(currentDate).subtract(24, 'hours').format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
    var pastWeek = moment(currentDate).subtract(7, 'days').format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
    var options = {
        host: "api.github.com",
        path: '/repos/' + userName + '/' + repo + '/issues',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)'}
    }
    var request1 = https.request(options, function (response) {
        var body = '';
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
            var json = JSON.parse(body);
            var currentDate = new Date();
            getPastDayIssues(json,pastDay, pastWeek).then(function(data){
                res.send({"total" : data});
            });

        });
    })
    request1.on('error', function (e) {
        console.error('and the error is ' + e);
    });
    request1.end();
});

function getPastDayIssues(issues, pastDate, pastWeek) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var i=0;var j=0;var k=0;
        var total = {};
        total.all = issues.length;
        _.forEach(issues, function(data){
            var createdDate = new Date(data.created_at);
            var createdAt = moment(createdDate).format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        //Comparing the dates using Moment and adding it to an object
            if(moment(createdAt).isAfter(pastDate)){
                i = i+1;
                total.pastDay = i;
            }
            else if((moment(createdAt).isAfter(pastWeek)) &&( moment(createdAt).isBefore(pastDate))){
                j = j+1;
                total.pastWeek = j;
            }
            else if((moment(createdAt).isBefore(pastWeek)) ){
                k = k+1;
                total.pastAll = k;
            }
        });
        resolve(total);
    });
}

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17004592/382982) answer?

Comment: Can you show your `./server.js` code too please?

Comment: @Paul hey Paul I have put in my server.js codes.

Comment: @Paul just done the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your error is because you're requiring node modules which are not in your package.json file (and therefore not being imported into your app's dyno when Heroku stands it up).

For example, `underscore-node`.

As a habit, I always do `npm install <modulename> --save` to make sure it gets into the package.json.