# TypeError: Cannot read property 'messageBody' of undefined

Tags: swift, api, heroku, websocket, socket.io

i want to send a Message in my app through the api im using

(https://github.com/devslopes-learn/mac-chat-api)

Always when i attemp to send a message i get this error in heroku terminal logs:

[image]

I tried everything but can't seem to figure out why that happens. 
Btw i'm learning with this api on a course on Udemy.

here is my emit:

```
func sendMessage(messageBody: String, userId: String, channelId: String, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) {
    let user = UserDataService.instance
    socket.emit("newMessage", messageBody, userId, channelId, user.name, user.avatarName, user.avatarColor)
    completion(true)
}
```

and here i use the function:

```
@IBAction func sendMsgPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if AuthService.instance.isLoggedIn {
        guard let channelId = MessageService.instance.selectedChannel?.id else { return }
        guard let message = messageTxtField.text else { return }

        SocketService.instance.sendMessage(messageBody: message, userId: UserDataService.instance.id, channelId: channelId) { (success) in
            if success {
                self.messageTxtField.resignFirstResponder()
                self.messageTxtField.text = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried googling that error message and code related to heroku? eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322989/first-heroku-deploy-failed-error-code-h10

Comment: That's not the answer. I want the solution for that Messagebody undefined thing. And not how to get the app to run again after it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the SocketIOClient API docs for Swift [here](https://nuclearace.github.io/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Classes/SocketIOClient.html#/s:8SocketIO0A8IOClientC4emitySS_AA0A4Data_pdtF), you aren't passing the proper conforming `SocketData` object type and instead passing individual parameters. You should be creating an object for your data that conforms to `SocketData` that ensures your data can be represented in a socket.io packet. Below is basically a rehash of their example in their documentation:

```
struct CustomData: SocketData {
   let messageBody: String
   let userId: Int
   let channelId: Int
   let userName: String
   let avatarColor: String

   func socketRepresentation() -> SocketData {
       return [
           "messageBody": name, 
           "userId": userId,
           "channelId": channelId,
           "userName": userName,
           "avatarColor": avatarColor,
       ]
   }
}

let customData = CustomData(...)
socket.emit("newMessage", customData)
```