# problems Deploying my python app to heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I have recently been trying to deploy my application to Heroku. I was following the documentation and everything but I'm getting this error now.

```
2020-03-12T21:46:36.154267+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=semsar-flask.herokuapp.com request_id=8c7e6604-97a5-4f5c-ae62-6c2edb73a4bb fwd="217.164.64.29" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn wsgi: app
```

Wsgi.py:

```
from wbp import app
```

Did I make a mistake filling in those two files or what? Please do explain since I'm relatively new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `H10` error could mean many possibilities and answering all solutions here would be tedious. You should also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322989/first-heroku-deploy-failed-error-code-h10) and see if any of those are helpful.

Also try to avoid empty spaces in `Procfile`. So try changing from this

```
web: gunicorn wsgi: app
```

To this

```
web:gunicorn wsgi:app
```

and see if it works.

Comment: The Procfile format is `<process type>: <command>`, not `<process type>:<command>` see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Comment: Removing those two spaces seems to somehow fix my issue but now I'm getting this error ' at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" '

Comment: please do update the new error trace to the question. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804507/h14-error-in-heroku-no-web-processes-running

Comment: @Tin_Nguyen True. The format just illustrates with placeholders and doesn't say anything about spaces. Believe it or not, I had this error and fixed it with doing just that. A similar incident also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54790377/6505847).

Comment: Oh I fixed that error too.. I just didn't know about the whole dynos thing. I didn't have any assigned for my app. anyways thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 1):

For the app crashed h10 error check that your SECRET_KEY is added to Heroku. Also when logged in to Heroku, click on 'More' in the top right of the page and then 'Restart all dynos'. Both have helped me in the past with this specific error.

Comment: How do I go around adding my SECRET_KEY to Heroku though? shouldn't it be automatically detected when the app is deployed on the platform?

Comment: No, you'd need to add it to Heroku. In the Settings tab click on Reveal Config Vars and you'll you can enter it there.